# giving a string slot in Amazon alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm new to alexa. I learnt and started to build a weather app.

right now I'm able to get weather data, but on the below condition,

I've craeated a custom slot(LIST_OF_CITIES) to hold Cities as below.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "WeatherIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "city",
          "type": "LIST_OF_CITIES"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    ]
}
```

and in my custom slot I gave as below.

```
Type               Values
LIST_OF_CITIES     Hyderabad | pune | london
```

and below are my Utterances

```
WeatherIntent give me {city} climate
WeatherIntent {city}
WeatherIntent what's the climate in {city}
WeatherIntent what's the weather in {city}
WeatherIntent {city}
```

when I run my program using any of the three cities mentioned in the above table, I'm able to get the correct. If I use anything apart from the above, it is sending back value as -4.

If I want to get tempreature of some other city, I need to add that city in the slot list.

Please let me know how can I get the vaues dynamically, I mean with out depending on the LIST_OF_CITIES, If I enter a city name, it should send back the result.

Also I tried adding type as LITERAL and also as AMAZON.LITERAL. When I saved it, I get the exception as

```
Error: There was a problem with your request: Unknown slot name '{city}'. Occurred in sample 'WeatherIntent get me weather of {city}' on line 1.
Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon provides some [default list Slot Types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#list-slot-types) for cities or even regions. E.g.

- `AMAZON.US_CITY`
- `AMAZON.AT_CITY`
- `AMAZON.DE_REGION`
- ...

You can use these as type when defining your custom slot.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use LITERAL - it is deprecated and isn't even supported at all outside US region.

And no, you can't manage the list of words dynamically.

Alexa will try to match what the user says with your LIST_OF_CITIES, and will try to return one of those words, but might return something else if it can't match one of those (as you have seen).

There are some custom slot types for cities that you can use and build off of, see here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#h2_custom_syntax

But that probably won't work for you since each of them is just one country, so you will need to build your own list of cities (in your LIST_OF_CITIES).